# Differentiating between two programs (windows)

Tags: windows, audio, permissions, code, audio-conversion

Is there any specific manner/way in which Windows differentiates between two programs?  For instance, why can't I run two of the same programs at once? Or is there a way in which I could do this by modifying any program/registry files?

Comment: The program needs to be designed to install that way.   Rarely is that needed as there are other ways for programs to multi-task.  For example you can have two independent windows in a browser logged in to different sessions.  Do you have a reason for asking this question?.

Comment: The concept you're overlooking/missing is *process* (or "job", esp in a batch context).  In order to execute a program, the OS creates a *process* for it, and assigns a process ID.  Executing a program two times in a row involves two processes, just like executing two instances of the program concurrently.  Although a program could be written to execute only a single copy at a time.  *"why can't I run two of the same programs at once?"* -- What did you try?

Comment: Windows perfers to use the term "task" rather than "process".  Hence the ***Task Manager*** that can show you all the processes that are executing/sleeping/idling.

Comment: Since your post is tagged with `audio conversion`, a program that used hardware that cannot be shared would be written so that it had exclusive use of that HW, and only a single copy of that program can execute at a time.  In fact any other program that tried to use such HW (e.g. a sound adapter or "card") would not be able to execute.

Comment: short answer is that there probably isn't anything you can do about the underlying problem you are having. it takes effort to restrict an app to just one instance (the default "not doing anything" stance on windows is to allow multiple instances), so the programming team that developed the app had a good reason for restricting execution. this might be because of a design preference, and in those cases there may be a configuration you can set to change the behavior, but 9 times out of 10, the reason is that the app just won;t work right with multiple instances. sawdust explains some of why.

Comment: If you're doing audio conversion just find a batch converter that can multi-thread, rather than trying to make it 'run twice'. If you're doing DAW-type work, then you'd need something like ReWire to be able to multi-task audio processing without dropping sync. [I'm on Mac, idk the Windows equivalents of these things.]

Comment: As for my reason for doing this I'm attempting to run two of the same browser at a time and I also want be able to have these two seperate instances recognised as being different within the windows audio system, allowing me to route seperate sound cards to the two instances. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ahh, ok, its a browser. So that means you are getting different processes already, but because they are grouped under a parent process, you cannot do what you want. hmmm. Browsers in the modern era use special multi-process operations for rendering (for performance and security purposes) so the programs themselves have been very carefully and specifically written to control their process invocation, and device access.  That makes this particularly intractable. can you use two different browsers (for instance chrome for one and Firefox for another)? that's about all you could do.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is nothing built into windows to stop multiple executions of an executable.  If a second copy does not run, then the author has designed it that way.

### Why would someone restrict it?

For one of our apps, we found the users would open a copy, start editing a bill.  They would then go away for a break.  In the meantime, someone else wanting to use the computer for something else would minimize our application.  The original user would come back, not find the application and start another copy. And not finding the bill already open would try to open another copy. Of course, the application would tell them it was already locked by them.  But they would refuse to believe it and ring support all the time.

Our solution was to make sure only one instance would run.  And attempting to run a second copy would kill it and make the original one come into view.

### How is this done?

There are a number of methods, most involving some sort of windows inter-process communication

1. Send a Windows **Message** (message, pipe)
2. Use a **Semaphore** (mutex)
3. Use **Find Window** to see if it's already running
4. Use database **locking**

We were finding the window and then sending a targeted message to it.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour varies from one program to another (specific build instructions that restrict or allow to run multiple instances of one binary image).
In some cases program has configuration option that allow to run several instances of it.
To simplify the way of using multiple "copies" of one binary you can just run the second (third, etc.) instance of .exe as another user (it should be created before).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).